# Unable to run a QT project on Windows (Qt5Network.dll is missing + MinGW wrong configuration)

Tags: c++, qt, configuration, mingw, clion

I'm trying to run a Qt project built with CMake using CLion. I have installed Qt 5.15, mingw81_64 and the following is the CmakeLists:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1.0)

project(CoText-client)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "3.7.0")
    set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
endif()

IF(WIN32)
    SET(OS_SPECIFIC_LIBS netapi32 wsock32)
ENDIF(WIN32)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Gui REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Network REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Sql REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Svg REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS PrintSupport REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt5WebSockets REQUIRED)

file(GLOB CLIENT "*.h" "*.cpp")
file(GLOB GUI "gui/*.h" "gui/*.cpp" "gui/*.ui" "gui/Resources.qrc")

add_executable(CoText-client main.cpp ${CLIENT} ${GUI} PingPacket.cpp PingPacket.h LoginPacket.cpp LoginPacket.h AccountPacket.cpp AccountPacket.h)

target_link_libraries(CoText-client Qt5::Core Qt5::Widgets Qt5::Gui Qt5::Network Qt5::Sql Qt5::Svg Qt5::PrintSupport Qt5::WebSockets ${OS_SPECIFIC_LIBS})
```

The CLion toolchain is configured for building using C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64 and in the CMake settings I've set -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\ as suggested from the CLion qt configuration help page (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#cmake-settings).

I'm able to build the project without any issue, but when I run it from CLion I get

```
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
```

and when I try to run it using the command prompt a dialog appears saying that "Qt5Network.dll is missing". I've also tried to use the mingw81_64 that comes under the Tools folder along with the Qt installation.

Comment: Did you add the location of the Qt dlls to your windows `PATH` environment variable and restart your IDE?

Comment: The can not find the dll has little to do with CMake and more to do with how your OS finds dlls. Although you could create a complex `CMake` macro to copy the dlls and fix it that way instead of adding an entry to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: 1. why do I need to add the folder containing the qt dll files if I'm specifying the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH?
2. now when I try to laungh the executable from the command prompt I get this error "_Z11qt_assert_xPKcS0_S0_i" and from CLion it finishes with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)

Comment: ***why do I need to add the folder containing the qt dll files*** Because Windows needs to find them when trying to execute your program. If they are not in one of the folders of the `PATH` or the same directory as your executable windows will not find them. With that said CLion may have its own setting of the PATH environment variable.

Comment: `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` is about configuring the project. This has nothing to do with runtime behavior.

Comment: if I add the C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin to the PATH I don't need to set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, why?

Comment: The two settings are independent of each other.

Comment: could it be that visual studio is conflicting with my project in loading the dlls?

Comment: if you have Visual Studio built Qt in the PATH before mingw dlls yes you can certainly have a conflict and undefined behavior. A solution could be to copy the correct dlls to the folder containing your executable. You also need to copy the `platforms` folder to the folder containing your executable.

Comment: I've uninstalled visual studio and now clion gaves me "CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    CMAKE_PATH_PREFIX"

Comment: I think that the warning is unrelated to uninstalling Visual Studio however I don't believe you have to compile at all to fix this problem. You already have an executable your problem is windows does not know where the dlls for Qt are located.

Comment: to solve the problem I had to add the C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin folder as the working directory in CLion otherwise I have to add C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\bin and C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin to the PATH variable, why isn't this mentioned anywhere?

Comment: Probably because it is about learning how your OS works (behind the scenes) or they expected you to have used a third party dll before this. As a `c++` programmer you sometimes have to know more about the system then you would a higher level language.

Comment: I'm still trying to figuring out why setting -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\Qt\5.15.0\mingw81_64\lib\cmake\Qt5 (that contains the Qt5config.cmake file cmake was expecting) doesn't help CMake when it builds and fails, what's wrong?

Comment: I don't see where the build failed in any of your output. So I can't help with that.

Comment: If you are still talking about the application crash because the lack of the dlls, `DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` has nothing to do with that ( unless CLion is has some special CMake scripts that I don't know about).

Comment: This link talks about the problem of the dlls and it also showed how to add the PATH environment variable in CLion: [https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#troubleshooting](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#troubleshooting)